# R to Python subsetting via vector

Tags: python, r, pandas, subset

I'm a python newbie but have some R experience.  In R if I'd like to subset a data.frame I can use a variable to do something like this:

```
# Columns

# Assign column names to variable
colsToUse <- c('col1','col2','col3')

# Use variable to subset
df2 <- df1[,colsToUse]

# Rows

# Assign column names to variable
rowsToUse <- sample(1:nrows(df1), 500)

# Use variable to subset
df3 <- df1[rowsToUse,]
```

How would I do this in python?

Comment: What sort of data structure do you plan on using in Python? Lists? Arrays? And do you want to subset by index or value?

Comment: @CactusWoman: Pandas/Numpy - end target is scikit-learn.  I'm trying to create test/train subsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your stated use of `pandas`

```
colsToUse = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
rowsToUse = np.random.choice(range(len(df1)), 500)

df2 = df1.ix[:, colsToUse]
df3 = df1.ix[rowsToUse, :]
```

There are also some other `DataFrame` helper functions for indexing: `df1.loc`, `df1.iloc`, and `df1.xs`.

It's also helpful to look at the guide [NumPy for MATLAB Users](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) which also often answers questions for R users too, at least when dealing with just a `numpy.ndarray`).